# Waf build system lacking permissions in Cloud9 IDE workspace

Tags: python, cloud9-ide, waf

I am trying to use the Waf build system to handle a project using C and Python. The builder itself depends on Python 2.6.x minimum which the Cloud9 workspace provides. On execution of Waf I receive the following permission error:

```
$ ./waf-1.7.13 --help
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./waf-1.7.13", line 163, in <module>
    Scripting.waf_entry_point(cwd, VERSION, wafdir)
  File "/var/lib/stickshift/[checkSum]/app-root/data/658231/.waf-1.7.13-5a064c2686fe54de4e11018d22148cfc/waflib/Scripting.py", line 31, in waf_entry_point
    lst=os.listdir(cur)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/stickshift'
```

It would appear that my working directory is `/var/lib/stickshift/[checkSum]/app-root/data` and I have read permissions up till `/var/lib/stickshift`.

I believe Waf is traversing directories to look for build utilities without checking the environment first. Any pointers would be appreciated--I don't think this is a cloud9 issue as much as it is a Waf in an unusual environment issue.